# How can I make this code wait until a Thread is available in the Thread Pool?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, networking

I wanted to practice a little on Network Programming and Thread Pools with Java. Here is a sample code I written:

```
/* User: koray@tugay.biz Date: 21/02/15 Time: 13:30 */

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MyServer {

    static List<ServerSocketThread> myThreadPool = new ArrayList<ServerSocketThread>();
    static int numberOfCurrentConnections = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8888);

        ServerSocketThread threadOne = new ServerSocketThread(null);
        ServerSocketThread threadTwo = new ServerSocketThread(null);

        myThreadPool.add(threadOne);
        myThreadPool.add(threadTwo);

        while (true) {
            if(numberOfCurrentConnections < 2) {
                Socket accept = serverSocket.accept();
                ServerSocketThread thread = myThreadPool.get(numberOfCurrentConnections);
                thread.setSocket(accept);
                thread.start();
                numberOfCurrentConnections++;
            } else {
                // I want to force the client to wait until a new Thread is available from the pool.
            }
        }

    }

    public static void informFinished() {
        numberOfCurrentConnections--;
    }

}
```

and the ServerSocketThread class is as follows:

```
/* User: koray@tugay.biz Date: 21/02/15 Time: 18:14 */

import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ServerSocketThread extends Thread {

    Socket socket;

    public ServerSocketThread(Socket accept) {
        this.socket = accept;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
            String readLine;

            while (!(readLine = scanner.nextLine()).equals("bye")) {
                System.out.println(readLine);
            }

            new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream()).write("Bye then..");
            socket.close();
            MyServer.informFinished();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void setSocket(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
    }

}
```

Well I can connect to my server with 2 different terminals like this just fine:

```
Korays-MacBook-Pro:~ koraytugay$ telnet localhost 8888
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
laylay
bombom
```

And the 3rd connection (if made) will not be served as there are 2 Threads only in the Thread Pool. But I can not find a way to make the 3rd client wait until a client says "bye". What I want to do is, after one of the 2 first connected clients disconnect, a Thread is allocated to the waiting 3rd Client, but how?

Comment: Would a [semaphore](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) be the answer in this case?

Comment: Well, use a real thread pool. Not an ArrayList. Read the javadoc of `Executors`.

Comment: @JBNizet I am trying to learn so I am trying to come up with my own solutions.

Comment: @KorayTugay designing a thread pool is an extremely complex task. You're just grasping the basics of references and arguments passing. It's way too early for you to try reinventing such a complex wheel.

Comment: @JBNizet My previous question was not about references and argument passing, it was about immutable Integer class which I did not know. Well I will try to find a solution to this problem as well, maybe it is early but still..

Comment: No, you're incorrect. If you had passed a mutable argument (i.e. an AtomicInteger for example), and used the same code, you would also have gotten null. Immutability doesn't have anything to do with the problem you faced. You confused "assigning a new value to a reference" with "modifying the state of an object".

Comment: @JBNizet Ok, as you say..

Comment: @JBNizet Could you check my answer?

Comment: It has several problems: the stack and the numberOfConnections are accessed from several threads without synchronization. And when a third client connects, instead of blocking until a thread is available, it goes into a busy loop, constantly checking if numberOfCurrentConnections is < 2, and eating the CPU doing nothing.

Comment: @JBNizet Ok thanks for the feedback, but this is a Thread Pool right? The main idea is ok?

Comment: No, it's not. A Thread can be started only once. And your code tries to restart it several times. The idea of a thread pool is not to restart threads multiple times (which is not allowed), but to submit tasks to threads.

Comment: @JBNizet My code does not start Threads several times. There are 2 Threads and they start only at constructor of MyConnectionAccepter.

Comment: That's not so. You call `start()` every time you get a thread from the pool in the `accept()` loop. It won't work. @JBNizet is correct.

Comment: @EJP we are talking about my answer not the question

Comment: @KorayTugay Indeed, I mixed up the two. You're not restarting threads, but the threads go into a busy loop instead of blocking until a socket is available. That's bad. It will make your CPU go to 100% doing nothing. An infinite loop is not a good way of blocking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my own question, I made it work like this:

```
/* User: koray@tugay.biz Date: 21/02/15 Time: 21:12 */

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Stack;

public class MyConnectionAccepter {

    private Stack<MySocketThread> mySocketThreads = new Stack<MySocketThread>();
    private volatile int currentNumberOfConnections = 0;

    public MyConnectionAccepter() {

        MySocketThread mySocketThreadOne = new MySocketThread(this);
        MySocketThread mySocketThreadTwo = new MySocketThread(this);

        mySocketThreadOne.setDaemon(true);
        mySocketThreadTwo.setDaemon(true);

        mySocketThreadOne.start();
        mySocketThreadTwo.start();

        mySocketThreads.push(mySocketThreadOne);
        mySocketThreads.push(mySocketThreadTwo);

    }

    public void start() throws IOException {

        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8888);

        while (true) {
            while (currentNumberOfConnections < 2) {
                System.out.println("Blocking now:");
                Socket accept = serverSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("Connection accepted..");
                MySocketThread mySocketThread = mySocketThreads.pop();
                mySocketThread.setSocket(accept);
                System.out.println("Incrementing connections..");
                currentNumberOfConnections++;
                System.out.println("End of while..");
            }
        }

    }

    public void informIAmDone(MySocketThread mySocketThread) {
        mySocketThreads.push(mySocketThread);
        currentNumberOfConnections--;
    }
}
```

and

```
/* User: koray@tugay.biz Date: 21/02/15 Time: 21:04 */

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MySocketThread extends Thread {

    private volatile Socket socket;
    MyConnectionAccepter myConnectionAccepter;

    public MySocketThread(MyConnectionAccepter myConnectionAccepter) {
        this.myConnectionAccepter = myConnectionAccepter;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void run() {
        System.out.println("Started...");
        serve();
    }

    public void setSocket(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
        System.out.println("Socket not null anymore..");
    }

    public void serve() {
        while(socket == null) {

        }
        while (socket != null) {
            Scanner scanner = null;
            try {
                scanner = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            String readLine;
            while (!(readLine = scanner.nextLine()).equals("bye")) {
                System.out.println(readLine);
            }
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            socket = null;
            myConnectionAccepter.informIAmDone(this);
        }
        serve();
    }

}
```

and the Test Class:

```
/* User: koray@tugay.biz Date: 21/02/15 Time: 21:18 */

import java.io.IOException;

public class MyTestClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        MyConnectionAccepter myConnectionAccepter = new MyConnectionAccepter();
        myConnectionAccepter.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you should create a threadpool as described in this article: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/thread-pools.html

So basically in addition to the pool of threads you also maintain a queue of tasks. Each thread in the pool is continuously polling the task queue for tasks. Whenever a task is available (queue is not empty), it is picked up by a thread and executed. In your case the task would be handling the client connection. The the number of threads in the pool is limited ( 2 in this case). So at any time number of connections that can be processed simultaneously is 2. Only when one of two threads is done executing the current task will it pick the next one. Each time you receive a new connection request, you add a new task to the queue.

Hope this helps!